# Karate - How to send request with client certificate from file system

Tags: ssl-certificate, karate

i have .cert file. .key file and Password pharse and end point. We are using keyStore, we are using file system. How can i pass these in my karate request.

Comment: its .crt file , its a typo

Comment: in postman i am able to add certificate as given in below linkhttps://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/05/set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman/

Comment: i provided refernce to postman so that my requirement/confusion can be understandable.

Comment: links working perfectly fine for me https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/05/set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman/   don't know why its not working for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to convert a `.crt` file, please read the docs and also this thread (long) may help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/281

Please update here with your findings so that it helps others and you can suggest changes to the docs if required.

Docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication

EDIT: as per comment below, solution is to create a keystore out of the `*.crt` file and a `.key` file, and then use Karate `configure ssl` to use the keystore.

Comment: I used openssl to create a keystore of .crt and .key file and used the karate ssl properties to paas the certificate

Comment: @KarateCoder is that a question or a solution, please be clear, thanks

Comment: Solution. we can make a keystore first, then use the karate properties to pass it in the request